# How do you do download the files folder from the Acquia cloud service?

Tags: drush, files, acquia-cloud

I just setup acquia cloud and have a site setup. I've did a git clone to my local desktop along with downloading the DB manually. But how do I get the files downloaded to my local desktop so I can do my own local testing?

Is there a quicker way to do this via drush to get the latest files and db pulled down?

Answer (score 9):

You can read up on some drush specific tasks that you can do in [this Elevated Third blog post](https://www.elevatedthird.com/article/adapting-acquia-cloud-api)

Acquia supplies drush commands and aliases that tie into [Acquia Cloud API](https://cloudapi.acquia.com/) calls. So you can actually simply use the alias and the `rsync` drush command:

```
drush rsync --progress @sitename.env:%files @localenv:%files
```

You can also create and download Acquia database backups with the `ac-database-instance-backup` and `ac-database-instance-backup-download` commands.

Also, if you want an "all-in-one" solution, the newer versions of Acquia DevDesktop tie directly to your Acquia cloud account and can get database and file syncs automatically.

Comment: what is @localenv, where does it come from? should I replace this with something else?

Comment: Try using `@self` instead of `@localenv` (will not work on some older versions of drush)

Comment: --progress is not a flag of drush rsync, it's an rsync flag. so the command should look like this:  `drush rsync @sitename.env:%files @localenv:%files -- --progress`